# what it's mean that code after return statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, return

it's not work if php code after return statement, it's confused me. what kind of situation we will write down the code after return statement?

```
function bar() {
    console.log('1', foo)
    foo = 10;
    console.log('2', foo)
    return;
    console.log('3', foo)
    function foo() {}
    console.log('4', foo)
}
```

And these

```
console.log('3', foo)
console.log('4', foo)
```

are not work.

only for Function declarations (hoisted)?

Comment: That looks a lot like JavaScript instead of PHP.

Comment: This is Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: Why are you declaring a function inside of another function? That function won't be available until `bar()` is ran, and then once it's ran, you won't be able to run `bar()` again because you will get an error saying `foo()` has already been declared. But that won't work either because of the `return;`, so `foo()` will never be declared.

Comment: it's my fault, it's should be javascript not php

Comment: Statements are not hoisted. Variable declarations (including function declarations) are not hoisted.

Comment: thx,  GrumpyCrouton. This code is from another thread. and thank for your explain it.

Comment: @Sumner Evans, maybe u misunderstand me. I  read https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp before I post it. this website say 'JavaScript Declarations are Hoisted' or u try to tell me 'JavaScript Initializations are Not Hoisted' ?

Comment: @KarlJhan, sorry, I meant to say "Statements are not hoisted. Variable declarations (including function declarations) **are** hoisted." Statements include `console.logs`.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you call `return` your script returns to it's caller so nothing after a `return` will ever be ran.

If you want the two `console.log` to be ran put them above the return.